# How can I get a node in jstree to display more than the title (I want to add a clickable link next to the title)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jstree

I'm trying to create a tree that has more than one block of text in the node (e.g., the title, and then a link that a user can click to create a new child of that node in the tree). Currently jstree doesn't seem to support this kind of thing, but I'm looking for any good workaround (not looking to put the link in a context menu).

I created the json hash this way:

```
    def item_to_json_hash(item)

    data = {:item_id => item.id, :data => html_for_item_data(item)}

    children = []

    if (item.has_children?)
        children_collection = item.children
        children_collection.each do |child|
            children << item_to_json_hash(child)
        end

        data[:children] = children
    end 

    return data
end

def html_for_item_data(item)
    return %Q|<table style='display: inline-block'><tr><td>#{item.data}</td><td><a href="/items/new?id=#{item.id}">New Child of Item</a></td></tr></table>|
end
```

I thought putting the two blocks of text into a long string with html markup would help, but the fact that jstree expects the node as a whole to be selected is interfering with the link inside of the node.

Here's my index, which shows the javascript to build the tree:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#collisterator_tree").jstree({
            core : { "html_titles" : true},
            themes : { "theme" : "classic" },
            "json_data" : {
                "ajax" : { 
                    "url" : "/items.json",
                    "data" : function(m) {
                            var html_data = m.attr                              
                            return { id : html_data ? m.attr("id") : 0 };
                        }
                }
            },
            plugins : ["themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
})
});
```

**EDIT**
Found my answer myself. Posting here in case anyone's interested. [Stack overflow question from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880364/jstree-nodes-dont-work-when-ui-plugin-is-used) gave me the hint I needed: removing "ui" from the plugins made my own links within the node clickable.