# Unable to replace contents of frame using javascript from another frame

Tags: javascript

I have frameset defined as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head>
<frameset cols="40%,*">
<frame src="FixSongsReport_00155_2013-09-05-13-13-46_index.html" name="nav">
<frame src="FixSongsReport_00155_2013-09-05-13-13-46_summary.html"  name="main">
</frameset>
```

On my left hand frame (nav) I a javascript function that includes this line

```
window.frameElement.frames[1].document.location.href = href
```

to try and update the right hand side frame (main) to point to the new href but it has no effect, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
top.frames["base_frame"].location = options;
```

instead of:

```
parent.base_frame.location.href = options;
```

it will work for u.

Where:

```
<frameset border="0" frameborder="0" rows="65,*">

        <frame src="index display on top" name="options">

        <frame src="pages i wanna display" name="base_frame">

    </frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an id to each frame and then do this, then replace your line with

document.getElementById('frame2').src= href;

I assume you already defined href in your code.

Comment: href is defined yes, so if I define a frameid in the frameset that will be visible to the nav html itself ?

Comment: Tried it and had no effect, if I add the line alert(href) I can confirm that the href value is correctly set

Comment: I meant add an id to each frame not to the frameset.Have you added the ID to the frameset? so <frame id='frame' ....> etc

Comment: I added an id to each frame in the frameset, no it didnt work but the other solution did work for me so never mind.