# Cant Go To Other php file nothing happens when i click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

When I Click The Patient Details Folder in the tree view section nothing happens it doesnt go to that url .. still same

i have tried to make an id and make a javascript still nothing happens ... also using php method

```
<a href="<?php echo 'patientinfo.php' ?>">Patient Details Folder</a>
```

Here Is Some Of The Code .....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav1').click(function() {
    $('#nav1').load('patientinfo.php');
  });
  $('#nav1').click(function() {
    $('#nav2').click(function() {
      $('#sample').load('patientinfo.php');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="treeBasic">
    <ul>
      <li data-jstree='{ "selected" : false  }'>
        <a href="patientinfo.php" id="nav1">Patient Details Folder</a>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li class="colored-icon">
          Admission Category
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

i just want when i click Patient details folder The Url Will Change To Specific Path ............
........
http://localhost/hospicemdv1/patientlist/consent.php ---- >

http://localhost/hospicemdv1/patientlist/patientinfo.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get I get leaf nodes in jstree to open their hyperlink when clicked when using jstree ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611317/how-to-get-i-get-leaf-nodes-in-jstree-to-open-their-hyperlink-when-clicked-when)

Comment: @BardGaming advisable to verify all your html tags are closed and open/close brackets etc are present and correct in your javscript prior to posting. There are numerous syntax checkers online if the errors aren't obvious to you or you need a fresh "pair of eyes" ..

Comment: i checked already they have closed tags